# Temporary ASP.NET directory: Which folder for which website?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-6, windows-server-2003

We have a multi-use web server that has a bunch of separate web applications hosted on the same server (IIS6, Windows 2K3).

Now, I'd like to clear the contents of the temporary asp.net files for a certain web application, however, how do we find out which directory in the temporary asp.net files maps to the appropriate website in IIS?

Thanks!
-Steve

Comment: Why do you want to do this, you can actually damage the performance of your application by doing this as you may cause your website to be constantly recompiled.  Maybe there is another approach to solving your problem?

Comment: The application changed the compile type as well as the version (from asp.net 1.1 to 2.0). It was causing namespace clashing issues due to previous temporary files in the same directory clashing with newly generated temporary files. It's basically a 1 time thing.

Comment: Rather, not the application, but one of the previous developers changed the version and compile type. Apologies.

Comment: If it's a one time thing, I would say just delete everything in the Temp ASP.NET folder, you're not going to do any damage you'll just force a recompile of all the apps.  Other than that, I don't have a specific answer, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not impact all of the other apps on the server (there are a bunch).